# How can I remove all JSON objects that have a certain key/value pair from an array of JSON objects?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to filter a dataset this like:

For example here's some fake dataset:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Sakura",
      "hasChildren": false,
      "livesInCity": true,
      "pets": [
          { 
              "cats": ["Luna", "Milk"],
              "type": "tabby"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Linn",
      "hasChildren": false,
      "livesInCity": true,
      "pets": [
          { 
              "cats": ["Luna"],
              "type": "tabby"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Donna",
      "hasChildren": false,
      "livesInCity": false,
      "pets": [
          { 
              "cats": ["Luna", "Milk"],
              "type": "tabby"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Tia",
      "hasChildren": false,
      "livesInCity": false,
      "pets": [
          { 
              "cats": ["Luna", "Milk"],
              "type": "tuxedo"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Dora",
      "hasChildren": false,
      "livesInCity": true,
      "pets": [
          { 
              "cats": ["Artemis", "Milk"],
              "type": "tuxedo"
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

I want to filter out everything that has `"livesInCity": false`:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Sakura",
      "hasChildren": false,
      "livesInCity": true,
      "pets": [
          { 
              "cats": ["Luna", "Milk"],
              "type": "tabby"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Linn",
      "hasChildren": false,
      "livesInCity": true,
      "pets": [
          { 
              "cats": ["Luna"],
              "type": "tabby"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Dora",
      "hasChildren": false,
      "livesInCity": true,
      "pets": [
          { 
              "cats": ["Artemis", "Milk"],
              "type": "tuxedo"
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

How can I do this? Is this possible?

In python I believe it's something like this, but I do not know how to get started in Swift:

```
people = [person for person in people if person.livesInCity == True]
```

Also, how can I filter this data set above to look like this - I want to categorize by type in name.

```
{
    "tabby": ["Sakura", "Linn"],
    "tuxedo": ["Dora"],
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Swift doesn't work directly with JSON. You first convert the JSON to Swift objects - in this case, this will be an array of objects, and then you use `.filter` function on an array with whatever logic you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can't work directly on JSON objects in Swift. They need to be converted first.

You can parse your JSON to a Swift object and then perform filtering, grouping etc.

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let hasChildren: Bool
    let livesInCity: Bool
    let pets: [Pet]
}

struct Pet: Codable {
    let cats: [String]
    let type: String
}
```

```
let jsonStr = "[{"name": "Sakura", ..." // your JSON string
let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!
let parsedObjects = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: data)
```

Then you can filter your parsedObjects:

```
let filteredObjects = parsedObjects.filter({ person in person.livesInCity == true })
```

or in shorter (*swiftier*) version:

```
let filteredObjects = parsedObjects.filter { $0.livesInCity }
```

You can also try to group by pet type:

```
var groupedDict = [String:[String]]()
filteredObjects.forEach{ person in
    person.pets.forEach { pet in
        if let _ = groupedDict[pet.type] {
            groupedDict[pet.type]!.append(person.name)
        } else {
            groupedDict[pet.type] = [person.name]
        }
    }
}
```

```
print(groupedDict)
//prints ["tabby": ["Sakura", "Linn"], "tuxedo": ["Dora"]]
```

If at any point you want to convert your objects back to JSON you can use:

```
let dictData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(groupedDict)
let dictStr = String(data: dictData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

```
print(dictStr)
//prints {"tabby":["Sakura","Linn"],"tuxedo":["Dora"]}
```

*Note*

For the sake of simplicity I used *forced optional unwrapping* (`!`) when decoding/encoding objects. You may want to use do-try-catch instead (to catch errors).

Comment: Not only that _Swift_ can't modify JSON objects, the thought of someone trying to modify JSON objects directly with any kind of tool gives me the creeps. JSON is a format for transport and possibly for storage, it's not a format that you should ever be tempted to edit.